# How to Dragging UILabel text?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Sorry for question.
But i don't understand.
How, when you click on the text, drag it to the right or left side to take his place was recorded value. And if you release UILabel then half way, then the value returned back to it previously. Swipe i realize to change value, and how drag value not.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an example of what you're trying to do. Even a picture would give us a better understanding as your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: Example - slide to unlock.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:  Create a slider with an outlet and an action.  Set it to go from 0 to 1, default value 0.    Implement your action as follows.

```
- (IBAction)userHasPushedSliderAllTheWayToTheRight:(id)sender
{
    if (self.slider.value != 1)
    {
        self.slider.value = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //trigger action here
    }
}
```

You can have the slider trigger the action using changedValue, which is the default action for sliders, but this may result in some unwanted behavior.  Change it to trigger upon both touchUpInside and touchUpOutside instead.

If you want the slider to start in the middle and have actions triggered on both the left and right side, then set the default value to 0.5, have actions for values of 0 and 1, and then make all other values reset the slider back to 0.5, like this:

```
- (IBAction)userHasPushedSliderAllTheWayToOneSide:(id)sender
{
    if (self.slider.value == 0)
    {
        //trigger left-side action
    }
    else if (self.slider.value == 1)
    {
        //trigger right-side action
    }
    else
    {
        self.slider.value == 0.5;
    }
}
```